# signet network Error: CreateBaseChainParams: Unknown chain sig

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, signet

What does this mean? I'm trying to work with signet to review some prs and I'm getting a fair amount of errors.

Comment: Is it verifying signet blocks to tip or is it stalling/exiting with these errors? Signet blocks are signed by one of the Signet administrators so it must be related to this. Can't yet find the error message in the code though. (I'm assuming this is the default signet and you aren't trying to set up a custom signet that you control)

Comment: Yes I'm using default signet. I'm going to try and reproduce it today.

Answer (score 1):

You have entered incomplete name in the `-chain` config option and error is thrown by [`CreateBaseChainParams()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/623745ca74cf3f54b474dac106f5802b7929503f/src/chainparamsbase.cpp#L54)

Incorrect:

```
$ bitcoind -chain=sig
Error: CreateBaseChainParams: Unknown chain sig.
```

Correct:

```
$ bitcoind -chain=signet
```

You can also use `-signet=1` instead of `-chain=signet`.

Comment: Maybe... Is this the problem @Kaizen?

Comment: I'm setting it to signet. I'm getting errors with other commands. I'm going to try and repo today. Thanks for your help!